# Estimation of certain Euler product using a symmetric square $L$-function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let 
$$
L(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)n^{-s}
$$
be a modular $L$-function of conductor $N$, and let

$$
F_d(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(d_0 n^2)}{(d_0 n^2)^s} \prod_{p|4Nnd}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1},
$$
where $d=d_0d_1^2$, $d_0$ is squarefree. In p.460 of 'Murty, M. Ram
; Murty, V. Kumar, Mean values of derivatives of modular L -series. 
Ann. of Math. (2)  133  (1991),  no. 3, 447–475.', the author says that 'by factoring $F_d(s)$ as an Euler product and using simple estimates, we find that
$$
|F_d(s)| \ll c^{v(d)}d_0^{1/2-\sigma}|L(2s,\mathrm{Sym}^2)\zeta(4s-2)^{-1}|,
$$ 
for $\sigma>3/4$. Here $c$ is an absolute positive constant and $v(d)$ is the number of prime factors of $d$.'

Howerver, I have no idea how to get this estimate.

Comment: How does it appear exactly ? $\frac{a(d_0 n^2)}{a(d_0)}$ is multiplicative and only the Euler factors of prime divisors of $d_0$ will be different to $a(n^2)$ so the main thing to estimate is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n^2) n^{-2s} \prod_{p|n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}=\prod_p( 1+\sum_{k \ge 1} a(p^{2k})\frac{1}{1+p^{-1}} p^{-2sk} )$ where $ a(p^{2k})=\alpha_p^{2k}+\beta_p^{2k}$, $1-a_p X+p^{k-1}X^2= (1-\alpha_p X)(1-\beta_p X)$.

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n^2)n^{-2s}\prod_{p|n}(1+1/p)^{-1}=\prod_p (1+\sum_{k \leq 1} a(p^{2k})\frac{1}{1+p^{-1}}p^{-2sk})$?

Comment: ?? a newform has multiplicative coefficients

Comment: Ah, sorry for my poor question. I see.